# How to delete any column containing too many NULL values?

Tags: python, sql, griddb

On my Ubuntu machine, I am using the Python client for GridDB. I need to search through a database stored in a GridDB container and delete the column(s) containing too many NULL values. The NULL values are "too many" when there are more NULL values than filled values in a single column.
How do I achieve that?

**EDIT:**

If there is data that looks like this:

```sql
 c1 |  c2  |  c3  |  c4  |  c5  |  c6  |  c7  |  c8  |  c9  |  c10
----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------
 42 | 33   | 42   | NULL | 12   | 33   | 24   | 15   | 75   | 80
 53 | 44   | 66   | 44   | 95   | NULL | 57   | 63   | 61   | NULL
 57 | NULL | NULL | 45   | 72   | NULL | 76   | 13   | 62   | 66
 75 | 49   | 23   | 89   | 67   | 22   | 12   | 52   | 22   | 66
 42 | 22   | NULL | 62   | 82   | NULL | 45   | 76   | 56   | 24
 64 | 10   | 71   | 81   | 85   | NULL | 90   | 72   | 62   | 73
```

The sixth column, `c6`, should be **dropped** since it contains four NULL values, which is more than half of the entire row count.

**End of EDIT**

I have tried to search through the GridDB documentation and SQL reference, but I still need a way to get all the information together and make my problem get solved. Could you help?

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. What is the structure of your data? When you say delete the columns, do you mean just delete the rows with the null data or to actually drop the column?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @CurtisCali I'm sorry, the column is actually dropped.